# Apache Camel: Get move path after file transfer

Tags: java, apache, apache-camel, camel-ftp

I am creating a file transfer route which is using `move` to set a dynamic path where the file is moved after successful file transfer. I have also setup a notifier to keep track of file transfer events.

As the move path is dynamic, I need to get the evaluated path where file was moved after the file transfer. How can this path inside the notifier?

```
public class MyFtpServiceBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        getContext()
            .getManagementStrategy()
            .addEventNotifier(new MyFtpServiceNotifier());

        from("file:C:/tmp/inputfolder?move=archive/${date:now:yyyyMMdd}/${file:onlyname}")
            .routeId("myRoute")
            .to("file:C:/tmp/outputfolder")

    }
}

public class MyFtpServiceNotifier extends EventNotifierSupport {

    @Override
    public void notify(EventObject event) throws Exception {
        Exchange exchange = ((AbstractExchangeEvent) event).getExchange();

        if (event instanceof ExchangeSentEvent) {

            // Want to get here the path where file was moved

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(EventObject event) {
        return event instanceof AbstractExchangeEvent;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add a header to the exchange, something like:

.setHeader("FILE_PROCESSED").simple("archive/${date:now:yyyyMMdd}/${file:onlyname}")

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to do it in a notifier, but you can always add a Processor and use the `FileEndpoint.getMove().evaluate()` method on the exchange to obtain the final moved file path.

For example:

```
@Override
public void process(final Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

    File movedFile = null;
    if (exchange.getFromEndpoint() instanceof FileEndpoint) {
        FileEndpoint fileEndpoint = (FileEndpoint) exchange.getFromEndpoint();
        String movePath = fileEndpoint.getMove().evaluate(exchange, String.class);
        File inputDir = fileEndpoint.getFile();
        movedFile = new File(inputDir, movePath);
    }

}
```